# Global Variables to store all CSS from Wordpress Shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need your input and insight on using GLOBALS variable to store all CSS that is generated through Wordpress Shortcodes. I have designed Shortcode that use the following css format:

```
 <style>
      #divID1 .blah { /* code */}
      #divID2 .blah { /* code */}
 </style>
```

this works well, however while validating through https://validator.w3.org I keep getting errors like below:

```
 - Element style is missing required attribute scoped.
```

or sometimes..

```
 - Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
```

Now my question is what if I keep adding that dynamic CSS code to one variable $GLOBALS['custom-css'] .= 'whatever code';

and I can print that variable within `<head>`. Is this insecure ? OR the $GLOBALS doesn't work on many hosts ? Or it may effect Wordpress site, I don't want to risk and ending up it not working on many different web hosts.

Can someone please explain and/or confirm if that is a right method.

Comment: "[`$GLOBALS` has essentially always been available in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)". I don't think that there exists PHP hosting that don't support global variables. Please note that global variables are something different from [`register_globals` configuration option](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) that has been removed in 5.4.0 (itself reached end of life September 3rd 2015). As for "right method" - this is subject to personal preferences.

Comment: Thanks Miloslaw..  since I am not very well versed with wordpress, I believe if I make am method to someone store all variables in GLOBALS, can I somehow use Wp_dequeue_style() or register them before ?.. thanks again for your answer..

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking, and I am afraid that comments are not the best place to tackle your issue. If this question that you have asked is closely related to general question you have posted, please edit it to include new information. If not, please ask new question.